# what is this syntax mean is c++ "class_name: class_ptr_1(nullptr), class_ptr_2(nullptr) {}"

Tags: c++, class, syntax, initialization, construct

I am not able to understand the syntax of

```
class_name: class_ptr_1(nullptr), class_ptr_2(nullptr) {}
```

Comment: These core C++ fundamentals should be explained in every C++ textbook, is there something specific in your textbook's explanation that's unclear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you mean

```
class_name() : class_ptr_1(nullptr), class_ptr_2(nullptr) {}
          ^^^
```

It is a constructor definition with a mem-initializer list. That is the class data members `class_ptr_1` and `class_ptr_2` are initialized in the mem-initializer list.

Here is an example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

struct Beginner
{
    Beginner() : first_name( "Deepak" ), last_name( "Singh" )
    {
    }

    std::string first_name;
    std::string last_name;
};

int main()
{
    Beginner beginner;

    std::cout << "first name: " << beginner.first_name
              << ", last name: " << beginner.last_name
              << '\n';
}
```

The program output is

```
first name: Deepak, last name: Singh
```